# How to fix "can't assign to function call" error in python using classes and allows it to run?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function where a user can buy ingredients from a store. The prices for each one are $1 and the ingredients are apples beets and carrots. The starting amount of money they have is $20 so everytime they purchase an ingredient it will go down how ever many they buy. 
So if they buy 3 apples then the total will become $17 left and the ingredients will add to the iinventory list.

```html
def buyingredient(name, number:int):
    global total
    if number*prices[name] > total:
        print("Not enough cash!")
    elif name == 'apple':
        int(iinventory.getApples()) += number
    elif name == 'beets':
        int(iinventory.getBeets()) += number
    elif name == 'carrots':
        int(iinventory.getCarrots()) += number
    total -= number*prices[name]
```

```html
class Iinventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.apple_num=0
        self.beets_num=0
        self.carrots_num=0
    def getApples(self):
        return int(self.apple_num)
    def getBeets(self):
        return int(self.beets_num)
    def getCarrots(self):
        return int(self.carrots_num)

iinventory=Iinventory()
```

However when I ran this, I get a "can't assign to function call" for the iinventory.getCarrots() portion so I was wondering how to go about this error?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of `getApples()`?  It returns `self.apple_num` as converted to an integer -- but it is *already* an integer.

Your code will be cleaner if you do away with the getter functions and just access the attributes directly:

```
elif name == 'apple':
    iinventory.apple_num += number
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

`int(iinventory.getCarrots()) += number`

What you want is:

`iinventory.carrots_num += number`

You may also create a method `addCarrots()`, so that you isolate the internal attribute from external calls, which has advantages in terms of testing and code maintainability. You could also rename the internal attribute to `self._carrot_num` and create a method `carrot_num` with a `@property` decorator.

Answer (score -1):

The portion:

```
int(iinventory.getCarrots()) += number
```

Translates to:

```
int(0) += number 
# (0 is the current value)
```

`int(0)` is a function call and it is illegal to assign to it.

So instead what you should do is remove the `getWhatever` methods and use this instead:

```
iinventory.carrots_num += 1
```

Since your functions return the named attribute, you can just directly access the attributes themselves. *Also, you don't need to use `int()` since it's already an integer*

Comment: It translates to `int(0) = number` which is illegal, as you cannot assign the result of a function call to be something else.